# Bx Slider second slide not showing on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

Having some trouble with my bx slider.
It works fine on desktop machines, and even works fine with you move the desktop screen down in size. But when you are on mobile devices the second slide image disappears.

The site is currently live here:
http://mistleymanor.com/

My html is:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/penthouse-bedroom.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/reception1.jpg" /></li>
</ul>

<!--BX Slider Plugin-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            infiniteLoop: true,
            auto: ($(".bxslider li").length > 1) ? true: false,
            pager: ($(".bxslider li").length > 1) ? true: false,
            controls: false
        });

        </script>
```

Im not sure whats going on, if anyone could help that would be great.

Lee

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to reproduce this problem with Chrome's device emulator set on Nexus 5. It seems the slide that's blank on mobile contains an image tag with a width and height set to 0.

```
<img src="http://mistleymanor.com/wp-content/themes/Mistley-Manor/images/reception1@2x.jpg" width="0" height="0">
```

Comment: I have managed to create it only on a mobile device, not by using Chromes emulator. Its strange, i have added a width and height and its still not showing.